# How to override a method with differents parameters

Tags: java, class, abstract

I have an abstract class with a method

```
public abstract boolean validate
```

And I have some other classes that extends the abstract one, but when I call validate from the other classes I never have the same number of parameters to validate, and I don't know if there is a way to solve it whithout making a validate method for all the possibilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each class that extends the abstract class, implement the method with respect to the class itself, so you will have a separate validate method for each class.

Also, please use google and try your best before posting a question without showing any efforts.